# select and update value inside same table using where

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to update the column values on the basis of the field. Means update `attribute_id`(46) against `entity_id` (maybe 13, or something else ) because i have different `entity_ids` for different entities.`attribute_id`(46) will get data from `attribute_id`(132) .What will be the query for this process?. for details please see the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Update tablename set attribute_id="xxx" where entity_id = "xx"

Comment: @Grumpy first i'v different attribute_id means list and second i want to pick value from attribute_id (132) and store that values inside attribute_id(46)

Comment: `maybe 13, or something else` and `entity_id will be dynamic, not static` ...We cannot build sql with "maybe"s. You need to better define your requirements.

Comment: @mickmackusa entity_id start from 12 to 2000, that's why I used the term dynamic.each have different values.

Answer (score 0):

Update same table field from table table with where conditions using this type of query. (Sorry, this query is not tested in sql)

```
UPDATE t2
SET attribute_id = (select attribute_id from xxtable  t2 where attribute_id = 132)
FROM xxtable t2
where attribute_id = 46
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a query like this:

```
UPDATE `tablename` a 
    INNER JOIN `tablename` b
    ON b.attribute_id = 132 AND b.entity_id = b.entity_id
    SET a.value = b.value  
    WHERE  a.attribute_id = 46 AND a.entity_id = 13 ;
```

Comment: entity_id will be dynamic, not static like you mentioned in a query? it may be 13,12 or any other value. Query first part seems fine but the second one I think not.entity_id will be the value of selected attribute_id=132 etc